# parse crontab line with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, cron

I have a web form, with text inputs for crontab values (minutes/hours/months/days), and I want to display user the next date of selected crontab task execution. For example, i have a values

`20 15 15 * *`, and the expected result will be: `"Next run: 15.06.2013, 15-20"`

Do you know any suitable javascript library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a library called [Later.js](https://github.com/bunkat/later)

which works like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>

<script src="https://raw.github.com/bunkat/later/master/later.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// create the desired schedule


// calculate the next 5 occurrences with a minimum resolution of 60 seconds, using local time
var s = cronParser().parse('* */5 * * * *', true);
var results = later(60, true).get(s, 20);

document.write('<p>Next Run:' + results[1].toLocaleString() + '</p>');


</script>
</html>
```

### You can check their [Example](https://github.com/bunkat/later/tree/master/examples) for more information

### Best Regards :)